# Can I show different colored points from kml files in Google-Maps overlays?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, kml

I extract the coordinate information from multiple kml files created by google's MyTracks app and merge them to create a consolidated file.  Those files have the following form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml>
<Document>
<Placemark><Point><coordinates> -125.362289,50.057000,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><Point><coordinates> -125.363414,50.058000,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><Point><coordinates> -125.372059,50.056000,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><Point><coordinates> -125.366759,50.058001,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><Point><coordinates> -125.376856,50.066001,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><Point><coordinates> -125.377394,50.067001,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

This code generates blue balloons in Google Map Maker (http://www.google.com/mapmaker).  I would like to know if this code can be modified to create different coloured balloons.  This will allow me to determine which points come from which source files.

Secondary questions:
(1) Can the balloons be shown as coloured points?  The balloons take a lot of visual space when I am working, so I would like to use smaller points if possible.
(2) Can the above code be made more compact?  The three tags "Placemark,Point,coordinates" seem like overkill for such a simple presentation.

If anyone is interested they can see more of my consolidated kml files here:
https://sites.google.com/site/keithkmlfiles/home/kmlfiles/point_files/snowden

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#custom_styles

Answer (score 0):

The following code produces 3 green pushpins and 3 default markers which are currently blue paddles in google map maker.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml>
<Document>
<Style id="TIcon">
  <IconStyle>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/grn-pushpin.png</href>
    </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark><styleUrl>#TIcon</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>  -125.362289,50.057000,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><styleUrl>#TIcon</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>  -125.363414,50.058000,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><styleUrl>#TIcon</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>  -125.372059,50.056000,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><Point><coordinates> -125.366759,50.058001,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><Point><coordinates> -125.376856,50.066001,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><Point><coordinates> -125.377394,50.067001,0.0 </coordinates></Point></Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

There's an exact copy of this code in the file at:
https://sites.google.com/site/keithkmlfiles/home/kmlfiles/test/two_colours.kml

If you go to: http://www.google.com/mapmaker 
    - move your cursor over the "Overlays" box.
    - click on "Manage Overlays".
    - copy the link for the above *.kml into the top box.
    - click Add.
    - click OK.

You can see what it does.